# Expressjs 4.X : Can i use router.route() instead of a app.route()

Tags: javascript, express

The Express 4.X suggests that app.use() can be used for a url that needs to perform different operations in get, post and other http requests.

For example :-

```
const app = express();

app.route('/events').all(function(req, res, next) {
  // runs for all HTTP verbs first
  // think of it as route specific middleware!
})
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(...);
})
.post(function(req, res, next) {
  // maybe add a new event...
});
```

**My Question is** :-

**(1)** Can i use router.route() in the same way, for the above written code ?

**(2)** Will the following code which is written above work with router.route() function instead of app.route() ?

```
// Will the following code work ?

const app = express();
const router = app.Router();

router.route('/events').all(function(req, res, next) {
  // runs for all HTTP verbs first
  // think of it as route specific middleware!
})
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(...);
})
.post(function(req, res, next) {
  // maybe add a new event...
});
```

Comment: Why not just execute the code and test it ?!

Comment: yes you can use that ,i should work fine